# Drawing a small steam locomotive with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, fun

Currently I am writing my master thesis in operational research, where my topic consists of locomotive assignment optimization. Hence I would love to have a small tikz locomotive for the head line of each site. Has anyone of you ever drawn such a sweet steam locomotive or something similar? 
Hope someone can help me because this would look very nice =)

Comment: I would use https://apps.apple.com/dk/app/pixel-perfect/id916097243?mt=12 or similar combined with https://www.mathcha.io/editor to create a clipart in TikZ.

Answer (score 2):

- Download some free clipart from the internet (start from Google/Images). Of course you should list somewhere the source of the images, maybe together with the author of the images.
- Include the images with `\includegraphics`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction to locomotives\hfill
\includegraphics[height=6ex]{kissclipart-peston-kaka-clipart-vyakti-aani-valli-peston-kaka-2f374a04382ffb98}}

Clipart from kissclipart\footnote{\href{https://www.kissclipart.com/peston-kaka-clipart-vyakti-aani-valli-peston-kaka-j48ots/}{www.kissclipart.com/peston-kaka-clipart-vyakti-aani-valli-peston-kaka-j48ots/}}.

\lipsum[1]

\section{More on locomotives\hfill\includegraphics[height=6ex]{kissclipart-thomas-the-tank-engine-png-clipart-thomas-train-pe-1dab55ebf9b5c263.png}}

Clipart from kissclipart\footnote{\href{https://www.kissclipart.com/thomas-the-tank-engine-png-clipart-thomas-train-pe-3doc3y/}{www.kissclipart.com/thomas-the-tank-engine-png-clipart-thomas-train-pe-3doc3y/}}.

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not really what I was searching for but it is really cool =)